# How to use the base case assumption when proving with 'induct' in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle, isar

Say I'm proving a theorem that assumes "`n ≥ m`" (both are natural numbers), and I apply induction on `n`. In the base case, the assumption is that "`n = 0`". With these two, we can conclude that, in the base case, "`m = 0`".

However, I'm having trouble in using the statement "`n = 0`":

```
lemma foo:
  assumes "(n::nat) ≥ (m::nat)"
  shows ...
proof (induct n)
  case 0
  have "m = 0" using <I don't know what to put here> assms by simp
  ...
qed
```

I've tried `using "n = 0"`, but it appears to be an "`Undefined fact`". I've also tried adding it as an assumption, but to no avail. Nonetheless, it is clear that it is an implicit assumption when analyzing the base case.

So, how may I use the assumption of the base case directly in my proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any assumptions that you need to be part of the induction need to be part of the proof state when you call `induct`. In particular, that should be all assumptions that contain the thing you do the induction over (i.e. all the ones that contain `n` in your case).

You should therefore do a `using assms` before the `proof`. Then `0 ≥ m` will be available to you in the base case, under the name `"0.prems"` (or just `0` for all of these plus the induction hypothesis, which in this case doesn't exist).